# Get Meteor collection object instance by name

Tags: meteor

I have seen similar questions but I think my scenario is a bit different. Say I define a collection like this:

```
MyCol = new Meteor.Collection("myCol"
```

and I want to get a reference to 'MyCol' using the string 'myCol' - I have created the function below which seems to work:

```
function GetCollectionObject(name) {
    for(var key in window) {
        var value = window[key];
        if (value instanceof Meteor.Collection) {
            if (value._name == name) {
                return value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

Is this the only/best/most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store your collections in a dictionary? It's *way* more efficient.

```
Dogs = new Meteor.Collection('dogs');
Cats = new Meteor.Collection('cats');
Alpacas = new Meteor.Collection('alpacas');

MyCollections = {
    dogs: Dogs,
    cats: Cats,
    alpacas: Alpacas,
};

...

MyCollections['dogs'].doSomething();
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this without maintaining any additional code but on second thought I think the overhead of a few extra lines of code outways my method.